# How to create a game entity class for game which will be extended with new methods dynamically?

Tags: c#, class, collections, xna, game-engine

So, I have a player class with basic actions. During the gameplay he unlocks new abilities. I don't know how to store new actions within the player class. To be precise - I know how, but my method is too messy and i want to clean up code. Also, I want to add to the enemies some of those abilities. In other words, every game entity(expect walls, perhaps :D) should have a collection to which i can add methods that extend entity functionality. How do i make this? Sorry, if my question is too abstact

Comment: Maybe an enum with the [Flags] attribute. So `EntityCanDo = Functionality.Jump | Functionality.Run` or a list of actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an action dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<string,Action> NameActionDic = new Dictionary<string,Action>();
```

Then you can populate it like this:

```
player.NameActionDic["jump"] = ()=>{ player.velocity.Y -= 5; };
```

And use like this:

```
if (KeyboardButtonPressed(Keys.ArrowUp))  // this is just an example
    player.NameActionDic["jump"]();
```

Just put the population code somewhere on the outskirts (separate `void` method, maybe player's constructor), or it will interfere with your edit and continue ability, because it's a lambda expression.

Comment: Oh, seems like it what I looking for! Thank you!